# how can i do responsive that background-attachment:fixed;?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to do like that: https://youtu.be/shgvBWJ-lTw?t=175

But when I do like that, it would not be responsive. How can i do that responsive in html, css, bootstrap?

I tried many things.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, there is not images from your code or website so i cant see what is actually happening and why your image is not responsive. Make section with **.container-fluid** So section will have 100% width and responsive, then edit your box with image in css like this:

**exapmle:**

```
.box is element where you want to apply your fixed background image.
.box{
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

- I'm not sure if this is going to help you but try it, if this doesn't help try to find another solution or next time send image with your code or website. :D